# Select filter hides all the items in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a select dropdown filter which dynamically gets its values and data from rest api.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <select data-filter="season" class="filter_category_name filter form-control"></select>
    <div class="listContent" id="listitem"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var data = [{
        "category_name": "1",
        "title": "One One",
        "more": [{
            "details": "some details"
        }]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "1",
        "title": "One Two",
        "more": [{
            "details": "some details"
        }]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "2",
        "title": "Two One",
        "more": [{
            "details": "some details"
        }]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "3",
        "title": "Three One",
        "more": [{
            "details": "some details"
        }]
}];


let listItems = "",
    categoryAll = "";

for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++) {

    var title = data[i].title,
        category_name = data[i].category_name;

    listItems += "<a onclick='createAVideoContainer(" + i + ")'><div class='listItem'><p>" + title + "</p></div></div></a>";

    if (categoryAll.indexOf("<option value='" + category_name + "'>" + category_name + "</option>") == -1) {
        categoryAll += "<option value='" + category_name + "'>" + category_name + "</option>";
    }
}

$("#listitem").html(listItems);
$(".filter_category_name").append(categoryAll);

var filtersObject = {};

$(".filter").on("change",function() {
    var filterName = $(this).data("filter"),
        filterVal = $(this).val();
    
    if (filterVal == "") {
        delete filtersObject[filterName];
    } else {
        filtersObject[filterName] = filterVal;
    }
    
    var filters = "";
    
    for (var key in filtersObject) {
          if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            filters += "[data-"+key+"='"+filtersObject[key]+"']";
          }
    }
    
    if (filters == "") {
        $(".listItem").show();
    } else {
        $(".listItem").hide();
        $(".listItem").hide().filter(filters).show();
    }
});
```

But for some reason it hides all the items and nothing change after changing the options

I want to initially load all the items and then filter based on the option

I want the select element to dynamically create the options with the values of the category names like the first option should have the value of cars1 and display all the other objects with the same category_name.

Note: The entire code is wrapped inside an async function which renders on page load.

Here is a proper [working js fiddle with the above problem](https://jsfiddle.net/AlkenDester/80qn2ve9/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information to help ... try to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that others can possibly assist. Even better, see if it's possible to create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that is runnable here on SO.

Comment: @PaulT. Unfortunately i am not able to create a stack snippet but the above code is wrapped inside a async function and rendered on page load. But i have updated the question can you please provide me with any solution for the above outcome to be possible

Comment: Unfortunately, still not enough to know... What does the relative html for the handling look like? In the added info, how does `category_name` relate to `data[i].categoryOne`, if these are related at all? What defines `data[i].tagOne`?

Comment: Sorry @PaulT. my bad i have fixed the above code typo i had previously defined the constants a bit differently in my code. if still there is a problem let me know ill try to arrange a working example.

Comment: Hey @PaulT. Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AlkenDester/80qn2ve9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your fiddle code, it would be better to filter the `<a>` items *within* the `listItem` area based on season, as that is the filter that is built, instead of trying to show/hide the entire `listItem` area.

The two minor code changes to achieve the desired result, is at these two code points:

1. Add a `data-season` reference here, to the `<a>` tags, with the `category_name` value:

   ```
   listItems += '<a data-season="' + category_name + '" ' 
             + "onclick='createAVideoContainer(" + i + ")'><div class='listItem'><p>" 
             + title + "</p></div></a>";
   ```
2. Change the filtering to filter on the `<a>` tags for the `data-season` that you build:

   ```
   if (filters == "") {
       $("a").show();
   } else {
       $("a").hide();
       $("a").filter(filters).show();
   }
   ```

Integrating those two changes into your fiddle example code, try the runnable example below:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "category_name": "1",
        "title": "One One",
        "more": [
            {
                "details": "some details"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "1",
        "title": "One Two",
        "more": [
            {
                "details": "some details"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "2",
        "title": "Two One",
        "more": [
            {
                "details": "some details"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "3",
        "title": "Three One",
        "more": [
            {
                "details": "some details"
            }
        ]
    },
];


let listItems = "",
  categoryAll = "";

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var title = data[i].title,
      category_name = data[i].category_name;

  listItems += '<a data-season="' + category_name + '"'
            + "onclick='createAVideoContainer(" + i + ")'><div class='listItem'><p>" 
            + title + "</p></div></a>";

  if (categoryAll.indexOf("<option value='" + category_name + "'>" + category_name + "</option>") == -1) {
      categoryAll += "<option value='" + category_name + "'>" + category_name + "</option>";
  }
}

$("#listitem").html(listItems);
$(".filter_category_name").append(categoryAll);

var filtersObject = {};

//on filter change
$(".filter").on("change",function() {
  var filterName = $(this).data("filter"),
      filterVal = $(this).val();

  if (filterVal == "") {
      delete filtersObject[filterName];
  } else {
      filtersObject[filterName] = filterVal;
  }

  var filters = "";

  for (var key in filtersObject) {
        if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          filters += "[data-"+key+"='"+filtersObject[key]+"']";
       }
  }

  if (filters == "") {
      $("a").show();
  } else {
      $("a").hide();
      $("a").filter(filters).show();
  }
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <select data-filter="season" class="filter_category_name filter form-control"></select>
        <div class="listContent" id="listitem">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u74w9qg1/) with the same change applied.

Comment: Thanks @Paul T. You saved me needed this for this week's assignment but was not able to achieve this feature in the existing project I was working on